# how to handle NA values in Target table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi Friends i have small doubt in sql server how to handle target table unmatched records  replace with NA.please tell mehow to solve this issue in sql server.

TableA:

```
   id    | Descr
   1     |ab
   2     |bc
   3     |de
   5     |
   6     |jk
```

TableB:

```
id  |  Descr
1   |
2   |
4   |
5   |
```

Here i want update tableB table Descr From TableA Based on id columns

i tried like below
   merge  TableB dest
  using  TbleA stag
  on dest.id=stag.id
  when matched then
   UPDATE

```
SET  
 dest.[id]= CASE WHEN coalesce(ltrim(rtrim(stag.[id])),'') = '' THEN 'NA' ELSE ltrim(rtrim(stag.[id])) END

 ,dest. [descr]=   CASE WHEN coalesce(ltrim(rtrim(stag.[descr])),'') = '' THEN 'NA' ELSE ltrim(rtrim(stag.[descr])) END
```

;
i got out put like below

TableB:

```
id  |  Descr
1   |  ab
2   |  bc
4   |  
5   |  NA
```

But i want output like below
TableB:

```
id  |  Descr
1   |  ab
2   |  bc
4   |  NA 
5   |  NA
```

Please tell me how to handle NA values in sql server

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join with the update statement and set descr to NA where it is NULL. Try this:

```
UPDATE dest
SET dest.descr = 
  CASE 
    WHEN coalesce(ltrim(rtrim(stag.[descr])),'') = '' THEN 'NA'
    WHEN stag.[descr] IS NULL THEN 'NA' 
    ELSE ltrim(rtrim(stag.[descr])) 
  END
FROM TableB dest
LEFT JOIN TableA stag on dest.id = stag.id;
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49f2b/10) to show it.